# CREATE DATABASE in stored procedure on azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

We have software that maintains some databases and that also can delete and created databases. Now we are porting it to Azure and we get the message:

```
The CREATE DATABASE statement must be the only statement in the batch.
```

So after some searching I come to 1 solution, run it as an EXEC (which already was the case). So we got some if statements checking up on a master database and then the following statement:

```
EXEC ('CREATE DATABASE [' + @databasename + ']');
```

(note that I simplified it, for testing cases)

So even when executed like that... I get that error.

I prefer to not move this code to the actual server code but solve it inside the stored procedure. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You didn't give us much to go on here but I suspect you are trying to do more in your dynamic than just creating an empty database? I have to say that needing a procedure to create and delete database routinely sounds like maybe changing the process is in order. The code you posted should work.

Comment: It did work but it doesn't in an Azure database for some reason.

Comment: I don't use Azure so I am not much help there. Why do you need to create databases so frequently that you  need a procedure to do it?

Comment: I don't need the procedure but this is how it is written and for maintainability I prefer not to change the code. But seems for now there is no choice.